# How to execute more than one query in sql using Java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am trying to execute more than one query by creating new statements,but it is not making any changes to the database.

Here is the code:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true","root","root");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
Statement st1=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select emp_id from emp_details where seat_num="+seat_num);
ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery("select max(id) from complaints");
String num = rs1.getString(1);
// System.out.println(num);
String emp_id = null;
if(rs.next()){
    emp_id = rs.getString(1);
    stmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mydb.complaints(emp_id,type,description,id,seat_num) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
    stmt.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(emp_id) );
    stmt.setString(2, type);
    stmt.setString(3, description);
    stmt.setInt(5,Integer.parseInt(seat_num));
    stmt.setInt(4,Integer.parseInt(num)+1);
    stmt.execute();
    con.close();
```

Comment: You have to do `conn.commit();` after `stmt.execute()`.

Comment: `commit()` only makes sense when the MySQL table engine is InnoDB @RedBoy so you don't have to do it `always`..

Comment: Debug time to find out if the code executes the code within `if(rs.next()){ }` .,, We can't help you with that because the code doesn't contain errors we can see.. By the way  the first query should also protected with a prepared statement

Comment: con.commit() isn't solving the problem !

Comment: if stmt is a PreparedStatement , I think your code is right.

Comment: @RedBoy Given the OP has not disabled auto-commit, there is no need to call `commit()` (and doing that when auto-commit is active should result in an exception).